# How can I install Entity Framework Power Tools for Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, ef-power-tools

I try to install Entity Framework Power Tools for Visual Studio 2017 but it does not see Visual Studio 2017. What should I do?

Answer (score 7):

I have a "preview" build published here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/pull/154#issuecomment-267394589 and the EF team plans to release sometime "soon"

**UPDATE** I have now released a [VS 2015/2017 version on VS MarketPlace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EntityFramework6PowerToolsCommunityEdition)

Comment: I have Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 [15.1 (26403.7)]. It doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Explain "it does not work" ??

Comment: I started the extension after I installed the extension. "Loading schema indormation..." and than "An error occurred while reverse engineering Code First. See the Output windows for details.". Error output is "Parameter is incorrect." http://i.hizliresim.com/O0bdd5.png

Comment: Yes, reverse engineering is broken, and will be removed in the release version - use the EF Tools, or the EF Reverse POCO template, they have the same features and are supported

Comment: @ErikEJ getting the error "Unrecognised element 'Providers'" when trying to rebuild views with this. It does seem to have installed ok though until trying to use it.

Comment: I have visual studio Enterprise 2017 and I am getting the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: @DanielBoteroCorrea Suggest you post an issue with more details on Github